# Create a cookie using Windows Forms C# Application?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I am writing an extension for IE using C# and Windows Forms / BHO Objects. I need to create a cookie which I can use to access information from other classes / forms in the app.

The various methods for creating cookies all seem to be related to ASP.NET and using the Http Response Filter, which do not help me here. I am not sure that I even need a session for what I am trying to accomplish, I just need to be able to create the cookie, access the information from the application, and then purge when needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions and cookies are web technology. You probably won't need to have that in your Windows application. Instead you can use a static class.

```
internal static class MySharedInfo {
    /* static proerties and whatever you need */
}
```

This is just one way. A really suitable method depends on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think you understand what I am trying to do. Should I still use a class if I am in fact planning store some sort of login credentials? I need to have this information stored so that I can access it from any class file in the app, for validating what the user can do, and also calling a web service. I assumed a cookie was the best route, but would I be able to access the information in this class from anywhere in the app? Sorry this is probably a noob question.

Comment: I would go for a central instance ( such as a static class ) to store that data. I would - personally - store an identifier for the user but take care no sensitive informations as passwords are stored longer than required. Regarding the web service it depends on the web service if it requires a session. But session has nothing to do with your locally running application, so this is another story. More like "How to access a session enabled web service from my windows application".

Comment: definitely, i will go the route of a static class, rather than a cookie. the web service does not need session, merely credentials every time it is called. thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I also used similar code for our application cookies.

```
 HttpWebRequest runTest;
 //...do login request
//get cookies from response

CookieContainer myContainer = new CookieContainer();
for (int i = 0; i < Response.Cookies.Count; i++)
{
 HttpCookie http_cookie = Request.Cookies[i];
 Cookie cookie = new Cookie(http_cookie.Name, http_cookie.Value, http_cookie.Path);
 myContainer.Add(new Uri(Request.Url.ToString()), cookie);
}

//later:
 HttpWebRequest request =       
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.url.com/foobar");
 request.CookieContainer = myContainer;
```