# How to send or post cookie from client to server in .net

Tags: c#, cookies, http-headers, httpcookie

I have implemented this code to request a page and read the cookies set by the server:

```
myURI = new Uri(strURI);
request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myURI);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.GetCookies(myURI);

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Cookie:");
        Console.WriteLine($"{cook.Name} = {cook.Value}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Domain: {cook.Domain}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Path: {cook.Path}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Port: {cook.Port}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Secure: {cook.Secure}");
        Console.WriteLine($"When issued: {cook.TimeStamp}");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create new cookies and send it to the browser cookies, so that the server can read them?

Comment: You can send the cookies to the browser using: `Response.Cookies.Add(HttpCookie(cook))` where `cook` is of type `HttpCookie`. If not then you need to cast each `cook` in to a `HttpCookie` and then add it to the response.

Comment: in C# Response.Cookies is not defined, although i imported system.web and system.net. Is it possible to show in code how to do that? which library should i import in this case

Comment: You can try `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies`. Which framework are you using for this?

Comment: Please show your `Controller` method where you are doing this.

Comment: I'm using .net framework 4.8 and i have added your line  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies and i got errer: object reference not set to an instance of an object: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.get returned null.
I think we need  first to connect somehow System.Web.HttpContext.Current  with request

Comment: The code that i have used is in Button click method, i dont use any controler, cause i did not work with asp.net and controller

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here. Cookies are used in web applications and the `Response` is for every request that we get from the browser, api etc. If you are using an asp.net webforms application then take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73079402/1807452

Comment: Is i possible to show simple code for this or Link?

Comment: What type of project are you working on? Are you using `Webforms`?

Comment: I' m using c# windows form application, I did not work with web forms and don't have know how about web forms

Comment: What i want to do is to write windows from app that can write data in a cookie, so that the webserver in the backend can read the data that i sotred in cookies and use it

Comment: You can read more here on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648480/create-a-cookie-using-windows-forms-c-sharp-application and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836208/send-cookie-to-web-application-using-system-windows-forms-browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClientHandler with CookieContainer to send requests with cookies.

For Post your request with cookies

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress + route) })
{
                                    
 cookieContainer.Add(client.BaseAddress, new Cookie(".AspNetCore.Identity.Application", "somevalue"));
 cookieContainer.Add(client.BaseAddress, new Cookie("Cookie1", "somevalue"));

  var message = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, client.BaseAddress)
  {
      //If you have json body
      Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
  };

  var result = client.SendAsync(message).Result;

  result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  }
```

And for reading cookies if you only have access to **HttpResponseMessage** You can read it from headers

```
 var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var item in result.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie"))
    {
        int startpoint = item.IndexOf("=") + 1;
        var headername = item.Substring(0, startpoint);

        if (headers.ContainsKey(headername)
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(headers[headername]))
            headers.Remove(headername);

        headers.Add(headername
            , item.Substring(startpoint, item.IndexOf(";") - startpoint));
    }
    var token = headers[".AspNetCore.Identity.Application="];//cookie value by name
```